# mysql Getting Average of several Columns with limit

Tags: mysql

Im trying to get an average of the last 60 items from 3 Columns each but im getting an error:

```
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias
```

this is the query:

```
SELECT AVG( Sensor1 ) , AVG( Sensor2 ) , AVG( Sensor3 ) 
FROM (

    SELECT Sensor1, Sensor2, Sensor3
    FROM temperatur
    ORDER BY Zeit DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 60
)
```

Im quite lost on the Alias I believe ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL requires an alias on all derived tables and subqueries and you are missing the alias after the closing parentheses:

```
SELECT AVG( d.Sensor1 ) , AVG( d.Sensor2 ) , AVG( d.Sensor3 ) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT Sensor1, Sensor2, Sensor3
    FROM temperatur
    ORDER BY Zeit DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 60
) d --- add this
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing at the sytax but I believe you need something more like this:

SELECT AVG( T.Sensor1 ) , AVG( T.Sensor2 ) , AVG( T.Sensor3 ) 
FROM (

```
SELECT Sensor1, Sensor2, Sensor3
FROM temperatur
ORDER BY Zeit DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 60
```

) T